# Using the epipolar line in a search algorithm to find corresponding points in two camera images

Tags: artificial-intelligence, computer-science, computer-vision

In computer vision, specifically computational stereo, we can easily write an algorithm to find corresponding points in the two camera images.  The algorithm can be written in pseudo-code like this:

```
Repeat for each feature point in the left image {
   calculate the epipolar line in the right image 
   if the epipolar line intersects only one feature point 
   then match those points and remove them from the lists
}
Until no feature point can be matched uniquely
```

My question is how can this algorithm be changed if three cameras are used instead of the standard two camera setup?

Just some good ideas or some altered version of this pseudo code would be brilliant.

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Once you have a matching pair of feature points between either of the images you can determine the intersection of these epipolar lines in the remaining image and determine the last feature that way.
So you can repeat your pseudocode for the "first and third" and "second and third" camera pair:

```
Repeat for each feature point in the first image {
   calculate the epipolar line in the second image 
   calculate the epipolar line in the third image
   if the epipolar line in either image intersects only one feature point {
     calculate epipolar line for matching feature point in the other image. 
     Intersection with epipolar line from first image gives the third point.
     remove triplet from the list
}
Until no feature point can be matched uniquely.
```

then

```
Repeat for each feature point in the second image {
   calculate the epipolar line in the third image
   if the epipolar line intersects only one feature point {
     calculate epipolar line for matching feature point in the first image. 
     Intersection with epipolar line from second image gives the third point.
     remove triplet from the list
}
Until no feature point can be matched uniquely starting from the second image.
```